# How to use custom fonts with OpenIMAJ

Tags: java, image-processing, openimaj

I am working on a project where I want to use custom fonts to draw text on image. I don't want to use the inbuilt OpenIMAJ fonts. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GeneralFont` class to access all system fonts via AWT:

```
MBFImage img = new MBFImage( 800, 600, 3 );
img.drawText( "OpenIMAJ", 20, 100, new GeneralFont("Arial", Font.PLAIN ), 120, RGBColour.WHITE );
```

Comment: I want to use other third-party fonts like google fonts